# Wp theme modification (gallery from portfolio)

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried everything and I can't modify my wp theme as I would like to.

With this [Niktitate WP theme home page](http://kopatheme.com/demo/nictitate/home-4/) I would like to use that Portfolio section as a gallery. The only problem is that at hover there are two links, one for opening the portfolio page and one for opening the image.

I would like to delete the link for the portfolio and remain just with the link which opens the specified image.

I really hope you can help, [here you can download the theme files](http://kopatheme.com/freebies/nictitate-multi-purpose-wordpress-theme-light-version/) where I couldn't find the answer.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: It will motivate others to help you if you include some code showing what you have tried in your question.

Comment: I've tried to edit the options_portfolio.php and kopa-shortcode.php files too with no succes. There are too many codes and tries to put it  here. I'm a starter but I'm constantly improveing, yet I'm not this good :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a child theme (you should do this as standard practice if you are already using a parent theme like Nictitate) and see if there is a template file for the gallery in the parent theme file structure. Duplicate the template file inside your child theme directory and edit it to remove the link that is created for the permalink.

Having a quick look at the Nictitate source code for one of the carousel elements it is related to a Kopa Carousel?? Not sure. You may want to raise a forum request to the theme/framework authors/support team.

Comment: Thank you. I can't find the respective code, that's why I'm asking for your help. I can't request help from the support because I'm using the free version of the theme ...

Comment: Install Chrome, right click the permalink icon (the chain links for Nictitate) and click "Inspect element". You can then open a few files in your theme to see if a URL is created with a class or ID the same as what is displayed. Once you find this file you should be able to duplicate it into your child theme and modify it to fit your needs. It's often a bit of trawling but if the files have fairly descriptive names you can quickly identify the right one. Is the gallery/slider a plugin? Can it be configured through WP-Admin?

Comment: I've found link-gallery , link-detail class and div class="da-thumbs-hover"> ... now I should find these somewhere to edit.

Comment: Do you have a URL to see what you've got so far?

Comment: I'm 95% sure thet [THIS](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dcfe68ed34bb58d1b460094181d7f39d4091b2d4) is the file where I have to delete the link, the hover-effect class is the one which I was looking for.